# Get previous month date javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How can I get previous month date in javascript. Suppose you have today's date like:

```
var abc = new date();
```

It will return today's date for example `03-11-2015`. Now I want to get `03-10-2015`. This is 30 days less than todays date. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

```
var d = new Date();
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() - 1);
```

Check out [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/), great little library for manipulating and formatting dates.

Comment: If you use setMonth(getMonth() - 1) on March 1, you'll get February 1 as an answer. If you're going for 30 days, try setDate(getDate() - 30). As of 2021, Momentjs' site advice us to look for alternatives to it https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/.

Answer (score 10):

Complementing Robert Shenton's answer:

```
var d = new Date();
var newMonth = d.getMonth() - 1;
if(newMonth < 0){
    newMonth += 12;
    d.setYear(d.getFullYear() - 1); // use getFullYear instead of getYear !
}
d.setMonth(newMonth);
```

Comment: Thank you if I want to format the date to dd/MM/yyyy then I have to write .format() or .tostring()?

Comment: Maybe you are looking for .toLocaleDateString() which will use a different format depending on the conventions of the visitor's language. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocaledatestring.asp

Comment: Yes I got it thanks. I have used format() for this. It works fine.

Comment: And yes moment.js is a very good javascript library.

Comment: Would this ever hit December? 0-1 = -1 then -1+12 = 11, never hitting december. You would actually need to add 13, right?

Comment: ahhh man, long week. Of course it would since we're counting 0 as 1, smh. My bad, and good work, this helped me out!

Comment: you should use d.getFullYear() -1 instead of d.getYear() -1

Comment: Checking for negative month is not necessary, as `var d = new Date(); d.setMonth(-1)` works as expected - for January 10, 2020 it results in December 10, 2019. So Robert Shenton's answer is sufficient.